# Error while using aroon function in R

Tags: r, trading, algorithmic-trading

I'm having a dataset like this:

```
            d        price  volume
1  2014-10-30  0.00000e+00 2534450
2  2014-10-30  0.00000e+00    2250
3  2014-10-30 -6.11322e-06    2800
4  2014-10-30 -4.27925e-05    1550
5  2014-10-30  9.78115e-05    1300
6  2014-10-30  1.10038e-04    2950
7  2014-10-30  6.11322e-05    1800
```

I'm applying `aroon` function from TTR package on this. If I'm using it in middle of my big function

```
pager <-data.frame()
pager <- aroon( data3[,c("price")], n=5 )
View(pager)
```

It throws an error

> Error in -low : invalid argument to unary operator

If I use it directly on the console it gives correct results 
Can anyone tell me where the problem is?

I'm using `TTR`, `quantmod`, `xts` and `zoo` packages.

```
Browse[1]> str(data3)
 chr [1:29, 1:3] "2014-10-30" "2014-10-30" "2014-10-30" "2014-10-30" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:29] "2" "3" "4" "5" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "d" "price" "volume"
Browse[1]> summary(data3)
          d               price        volume  
 2014-10-30:29    3.11774e-04: 3      1000: 3  
                  2.32302e-04: 2       900: 2  
                  3.17887e-04: 2       200: 1  
                  6.11322e-05: 2       400: 1  
                 -4.27925e-05: 1       500: 1  
                 -6.11322e-06: 1       600: 1  
                 (Other)     :18   (Other):20
```

Comment: I'm using TTR, Quantmod,Xts,zoo packages

Comment: Sorry but i can't able to understand what are you trying to say

Comment: it is `quantmod`, not `Quantmod`. It is `xts`, not `Xts`. R is case sensitive.

Comment: I dont think this is the problem sir, because i'm using R studio and i take the packages directly from the packages in the right side

Comment: I also said that it works fine if i use it in the console but not in the middle of any function

Comment: A lot of people don't use RStudio. Thus, `library(Quantmod)` will fail. Of course it is not the source of your problem, but it is considered as good manner to provide the correct syntax of the names of the packages you use.

Comment: could you please post the output of `str(data3)` and `summary(data3)`

Comment: Osssan , I edited my Question, Please see above

Answer (score 1):

The error is because the first argument you pass to the `aroon` function is not one of the following types: logical, integer, double, complex. You did not provide enough information for me to be more specific.

If I had to guess, I would say your data are either factor or character when that error is thrown.